# How to use a custom UIImage as an UITabBarItem Badge?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

How can I add a custom UIImage as the Badge for a UITabBarItem?
I.e It will show up when the badge value of the UITabbarItem is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider subclassing UITabBarItem and drawing it yourself

Comment: UITabBarItem doesn't even inherit from UIView. Can you please clarify your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Sascha Paulus wrote a great class that does just this:

[CustomBadge2.0](http://www.spaulus.com/2011/04/custombadge-2-0-retina-ready-scalable-light-reflex/?lang=en)

You can of course use it in combination with subclassing `UITabBarItem`.

Answer (score 0):

u can use the following custom class for CustomBadge:

https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge/tree/master/Classes

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can have a look inside [here](https://github.com/ratulSharker/UITabbarItem-CustomBadge). Here custom item is added as a [UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/). Consider using your own choices here.

## Demo

[image]

and only two line of code, to get you go

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  //supplying the animation parameter
  [UITabBarItem setDefaultAnimationProvider:[[DefaultTabbarBadgeAnimation alloc] init]];
  [UITabBarItem setDefaultConfigurationProvider:[[DefaultSystemLikeBadgeConfiguration alloc] init]];

  //rest of your code goes following...

  return YES;
}
```